# tsc incorrectly compiling .ts files into .js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

Hello I am using typescript and orbit-db in a project and I ran into this issue:

This code

```
this.orbitdb = new OrbitDB(this.ipfs);
```

For some reason compiles into:

```
this.orbitdb = new orbit_db_1.default(this.ipfs);
```

instead of

```
this.orbitdb = new orbit_db_1(this.ipfs);
```

I tried looking online for a fix but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need flags `esModuleInterop` and/or `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`